# Searching for Quotes, Brackets, and Newlines in Solr

Tags: lucene, solr

I've got a problem. I accidentally put some garbage in my index that looks like this:

```
[
  ""
]
```

That's space, newline, left bracket, newline, space, space, quote, quote, newline, right bracket.

I'm using Solr.StrField for this field. I have tried every possible combination of escape characters, url encodings, etc to try to query for documents that have this field, but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody know how I could query for a string like this?

Answer (score 1):

First escape the characters followed by encoding the query string.
"\ \n[\n\ \ \"\"\n]" should be encoded. First try from the browser without encoding.